# Pygame RogueLike window not launching when running function

Tags: python, pygame

When i try to run this piece of code the pygame window created in the game_start function does not launch.  When i remove the game_main_loop function it does.  I cannot figure out what is wrong with the function, anybody have any ideas?

```
#Modules
import libtcodpy as libtcod
import pygame

#Game Files
import constants

pygame.init()

def game_start():
    '''this function initialises the main window and the pygame library'''
    #initialise the game
    MAIN_SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((constants.WIDTH,constants.HEIGHT))


def game_main_loop():
    '''in this function the game is looped'''
    game_quit = False

    while not game_quit:
        #get player input
        event_list = pygame.event.get()

        #process player input
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_quit = True

        #draw the game
        #quit the game
    pygame.quit()
    exit()
```

Comment: Your first debugging step should be to comment out all the code from `game_main_loop` and see if the behavior remains the same.

Comment: where is rest of code - you defined functions but you don't execute them, so they can't create window.

Answer (score 1):

First, maybe unify your comments, either choose # or '''.

Second, possibly the screen is never initalized because it is not encompassing the entire file. Maybe remove `game_start` and use `set_mode` after your import statements.

Example:

```
#Modules
import libtcodpy as libtcod
import pygame

#Game Files
import constants

pygame.init()

MAIN_SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((constants.WIDTH,constants.HEIGHT))


def game_main_loop():
    '''in this function the game is looped'''
    game_quit = False

    while not game_quit:
        #get player input
        event_list = pygame.event.get()

        #process player input
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_quit = True

        #draw the game
        #quit the game
    pygame.quit()
    exit()
    # After, just call the game function
```

Maybe take a look at [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) while you are at it, It may be helpful later.

Comment: Use only `#` for comments, triple quotes `"""Bla bla"""` are for docstrings. Docstrings should explain the purpose of a function and how it should be used, comments should explain *why* something that isn't obvious is there.